# How to fetch a Mysql table data and put each row in different variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table with 4 column [Id, Name, Title Text]. I want to assign a variable with each key of every row. For

```
row 1 - id1, name1, title1, text1;
row 2 - id3, name2, title2, text2;
row 3 - id3, name3, title3, text3;
```

Here id1, name1... are variable that contain the value of that row.
By in my code, all values are going to same variable for each time. Here is my code..

```
$id1 = NULL;
$id2 = NULL;
$id3 = NULL;

$name1 = NULL;
$name2 = NULL;
$name3 = NULL;

$title1 = NULL;
$title2 = NULL;
$title3 = NULL;

$text1 = NULL; 
$text2 = NULL;
$text3 = NULL;

$query = "SELECT * FROM index_data";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id1 = $row["id"];
        $name1 = $row["name"];
        $title1 = $row["title"];
        $text1 = $row["text"];
    }

}
```

Here i got only the first row, how how can i get other two row with my associate variables? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using variables with numbers in their names that almost always indicates you should be using arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $i++;
        ${"id$i"} = $row["id"];
        ${"name$i"} = $row["name"];
        ${"title$i"} = $row["title"];
        ${"text$i"} = $row["text"];
    }
```

But you really should consider to use arrays.

Comment: You are welcome. So set my answer as accepted and thanks to that you will tell that this topic is solved.

Answer (score 1):

"Here i got only the first row"

Nope, you got multiple rows, but because you aren't doing anything with the data being defined in the while loop, the variables are simply redefined each time, and so you end up with one result.

Try this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    $info = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $info[$i] = [$row["id"], $row["name"], $row["title"], $row["text"]];
        $i++;
    }
}
```